# Scaling background of popup div

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, popup

I struggle with setting up a popup containing an image. I have a plain html doc where I try to open an image on the screen via clicking a div.

```
<body>
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="sample.png"</img>
    <span class="popupcontent" id="myPopup"></span>
  </div>
        <script>
        // When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
        function myFunction() {
          var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
          popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }
        </script>
</body>
```

The CSS rules are also pretty simple:

```
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  margin:auto;
  top:0%;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius:25px;
}
.popup .popupcontent {
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;:
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-image: url('image.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

However, when I click the div "popup" nothing happens.
I expected a popup to show up centered in the middle of the screen containing the defined background image.
What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score -1):

You missed a rule when you have written "popupcontent":

this is wrong:
`margin:aut;:`

do this instead:
`margin: auto;`